# multiple python packages in a single msi, exe, or egg

Tags: python, packaging

Is there a way to use the Python setup.py with bdist_wininst or bdist_msi to combine multiple packages?

I have to packages I develop (package *foo* that requires package *bar*). Most users just think of it as *foo* so I want to create a single windows MSI or executable that contains both "foo" and "bar".

I could do my checkout's such that I duplicate the the necessary install requirements in foo's setup.py for both foo and bar, this is error prone if *bar* adds any new files or directories.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/redist_wininst.py.html

Answer (score 1):

Installing multiple packages is simple if you specify multiple packages in the `setup()` function from setuptools:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    ...
    packages = ['package1', 'package2'],
    package_dir = {'':'src'},   # tell distutils packages are under src
    ...
)
```

[Link to the setuptools documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html)

Comment: I think I did not word well, but I'm looking creating a single package for what would normally be multiple packages...the closest thing I could find was: 

Create an Installation Bundle with Compiled Dependencies part of:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#id22

Comment: Ah, well in that case, in my example, you would put package1 and package2 in a directory called main_package. Then add an empty ```__init__.py``` file in main_package.

Then instead of ```packages = ['package1', 'package2']```, you would put ```packages = ['main_package']```.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already installed [**cx_Freeze**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze/4.3.4)  ;

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
setup(name="Game",
         version="1.0",
         options={"build_exe":{"packages":["pygame"],"include_files":["apple.png","snakehead.png","intro.wav","dead.wav"]}},
         description="the game",
         executables=[Executable("mygame.py")])
```

Put this `setup.py` with all of the packages and your main.py in a folder, open console **in** that folder and write;

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

Edit: This is an example from a game that I made, so you don't use `pygame` unless you are not using Pygame. As you see I had to put 2 png and 2 wav files, `include_files` is for packages.

[image]

They must be look like this in the same folder everything, after you open the cmd **in** this folder and ran that `bdist_msi`, the `msi` will in the `C/program files` . This screenshot from my folder, I move that msi to this file it's not creating in there. All other things except msi and zip file, must be in the same folder.

**For exe** the setup.py must be like this;

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
setup(name="Chuck Norris",
         version="1.0",
         description="as above",
         executables=[Executable("myfile.py")])
```

Open cmd in the same folder and;

```
python setup.py build
```

**But**, after you converted it to exe,It will make another folder and you have to put all of the packages in to that folder. Fonts,pictures,sounds etc. whatever include your program. With `bdist_msi` you do **not** have to store them in same folder after setup.py ran.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I'm looking for. I don't want to deploy as a standalone package. I want to deploy alongside other python package in the lib-sitepackages. However, I want the single MSI to deploy multiple packages

Comment: This is for single MSI for multiple packages already. As you see I have to put 2picture and 2 sounds to my game, done with single MSI.